# No se muestras las imágenes de texto enriquecido de contentful

Tags: reactjs, api, nextjs

Estoy intentando cambiar de cms sin cabeza de mi blog de `flamelink` a `contentful`. Ya conecte con el cms (no hay problema con eso) el inconveniente nace cuando se muestra el contenido en forma de texto enriquecido de `contentful`, se muestra el texto pero no se muestran las imágenes que tiene.

He intentado con el `documentToReacComponent`, con el `documentToHtmlString`, con la propiedad `danger`... de las etiquetas de html pero nada funciona. Le muestro el código que utilizo:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'   
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@content   ful/rich-text-react-renderer';
const contentful = require('contentful')           
import { documentToHtmlString } from '@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer';                                                                                  
export default function App(){                                                                              
const [page, setPage] = useState(null)                                                                   
useEffect(() => {                                                                                      
const client = contentful.createClient({               
space: 'xxxxxxx',                              
environment: 'master',                                              
accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'                                          
 })                                                                               
client.getEntry('9wiO6VUuha1syHdMLaq1a')                
.then((response) => 
setPage(response.fields.contenidoDeLaPublicacion)                                  
)                                                 
.catch(console.error)                                                                                
 }                                                                                                       
)
, [page];                                                                                                                                                                                                    
return(
         <>
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:
         documentToHtmlString(page)
         }} ></div>
         </>
       )
     }
```

Ese es el código que estoy utilizando para la conexión y renderizar.